# How to get from device-manager device (e.g. from its "Physical Device Object name") to its drive-letter?

Tags: winapi, wmi

From the device manager, I have a USB device node. I extracted its "Physical Device Object name" (e.g. `\Device\0000010f`).

Fighting for hours with `NtOpenDirectoryObject`, `NtQueryDirectoryObject`, `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject`, `NtQuerySymbolicLinkObject` and `QueryDosDevice`, I couldn't find a way to get from that "Physical Device Object name" to the actual drive-letter (`C:`, `D:`, ...).

I'm looking for any storage solution (USB/SATA/...). How do I do that?

---

(There are many similar questions, none of them answers e.g. how to get from Physical Device Object name to `\Device\HarddiskVolumeXYZ` or to `Volume{SOME_GUID}`)

Comment: There's no 1:1 mapping for this, you could have multiple drive letters mounted on the one physical device. Better to go through the drive letters one by one and find out their physical devices.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, of course, but there's 1:N mapping, and in this case I need all partitions mounted on that device (or vice versa - device from partition, doesn't matter). Ok - "Better to go through the drive letters one by one and find out their physicial devices" - how?

Comment: @Tar: There is no 1:N mapping either. A volume need not have a drive letter assigned. Drive letters are left-overs from the days when MS DOS was new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you view `\Device\0000010f` this is *PDO* (*Physical Device Object*) created by some bus driver (it have flag `DO_BUS_ENUMERATED_DEVICE`)

to it can be attached some *FDO* (*Functional Device Object*). if this is from storage stack (based on *CompatibleIDs* strings returned by bus device for this *PDO* ) typical *FDO* name have form `\Device\Harddisk%d\DR%d` and well known symbolic link to it `\Device\Harddisk%d\Partition0`

disk driver *FDO* enumerate partitions on volume and for every partition create *PDO* device object ( with well known symbolic link `\Device\Harddisk%d\Partition%d` where partition number always > 0, *Partition0* is refer to whole disk *FDO*)

usual partition is same as volume but not always ([Partitions and Volumes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163559.aspx)) also note [`IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365194(v=vs.85).aspx) - it return array of [`DISK_EXTENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363968(v=vs.85).aspx) structures - look here for `DiskNumber -The number of the disk that contains this extent.` so volume can placed on several disks. but in 99%+ [`IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365194(v=vs.85).aspx) return to you only *one* [`DISK_EXTENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363968(v=vs.85).aspx)

so what you can do if you have path to *PDO* in storage stack ?

1. open the device - if use [`ZwOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx) (of course this worked in
   user mode) we can use `\Device\0000010f` as is. if we want use win32
   api we need use prefix `\\?\GLOBALROOT` for all names. really we open by this bus *PDO* but because disk *FDO* is attached to *PDO* all our requests will be send via *FDO* and handled here. desired access ? `SYNCHRONIZE` is enough (in case `CreateFile` if we not set `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` api implicity add this flag to `DESIRED_ACCESS` )
2. send [`IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968800(v=vs.85).aspx) to device. check that
   `DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_DISK && sdn.PartitionNumber == 0`
3. send [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365174(v=vs.85).aspx) for get a variable-sized
   array of [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365448(v=vs.85).aspx) structures
4. based on `DeviceNumber` (which we get at step 2) and
   `PartitionNumber` (which we get at step 3) format symbolic link to
   partition *PDO* - `\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Harddisk%d\Partition%d`
5. open partition *PDO* with `SYNCHRONIZE` access (enough because all
   *IOCTL* which we use have `FILE_ANY_ACCESS` type
6. send [`IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560437(v=vs.85).aspx) to partition
7. now we need handle to MountManager device (`\\.\MountPointManager`)
   for send him `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_DOS_VOLUME_PATH` this *IOCTL* defined in `mountmgr.h` in input it require [`MOUNTDEV_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562256(v=vs.85).aspx)
   which we get at step 6. on output we receive `MOUNTMGR_VOLUME_PATHS`
   structure (also defined in `mountmgr.h`) alternatively we can use
   `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_DOS_VOLUME_PATHS` - if all ok we got list of
   drive letters like `C:`, `D:`, etc..
8. for enumerate disk drives in system we can use
   [`CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538415(v=vs.85).aspx) with
   `{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` filter, open every device
   instance by [`CM_Locate_DevNodeW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538742(v=vs.85).aspx) and finally query for
   [`DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542580(v=vs.85).aspx) by call
   [`CM_Get_DevNode_Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh780220(v=vs.85).aspx)

ok, here the code example correct which do all this:

```
#include <mountmgr.h>

// guz == 0 always, volatile for prevent CL "optimization" - it can drop alloca(0) call
static volatile UCHAR guz;

ULONG QueryPartitionW32(HANDLE hPartition, HANDLE hMountManager)
{
    MOUNTDEV_STABLE_GUID guid;
    ULONG dwBytesRet;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_STABLE_GUID, 0, 0, &guid, sizeof(guid), &dwBytesRet, NULL))
    {
        DbgPrint("StableGuid = \\\\?\\Volume{%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x}\n",
            guid.StableGuid.Data1, guid.StableGuid.Data2, guid.StableGuid.Data3,
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[0],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[1],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[2],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[3],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[4],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[5],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[6],
            guid.StableGuid.Data4[7]
        );
    }

    // assume NumberOfDiskExtents == 1
    VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS vde;
    if (DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, 0, 0, &vde, sizeof(vde), &dwBytesRet, 0))
    {
        if (vde.NumberOfDiskExtents)
        {
            DbgPrint("ofs=%I64u, len=%I64u\n", vde.Extents->StartingOffset.QuadPart, vde.Extents->ExtentLength.QuadPart);
        }
    }

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PMOUNTDEV_NAME pmdn;
    };

    ULONG err;
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(MOUNTDEV_NAME) + 0x10, InputBufferLength;

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME, 0, 0, buf, cb, &dwBytesRet, NULL))
        {
            DbgPrint("%.*S\n", pmdn->NameLength >> 1, pmdn->Name);

            union {
                PVOID pv;
                PMOUNTMGR_VOLUME_PATHS pmvp;
            };

            cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(MOUNTMGR_VOLUME_PATHS) + 0x10, InputBufferLength = sizeof(MOUNTDEV_NAME) + pmdn->NameLength;

            do 
            {
                if (cb < rcb)
                {
                    cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), pmdn);
                }

                if (DeviceIoControl(hMountManager, IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_DOS_VOLUME_PATH,
                    pmdn, InputBufferLength, pv, cb, &dwBytesRet, NULL))
                {
                    PWSTR sz = pmvp->MultiSz;

                    while(*sz)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);
                        sz += 1 + wcslen(sz);
                    }
                    return NOERROR;
                }

                rcb = sizeof(MOUNTMGR_VOLUME_PATHS) + pmvp->MultiSzLength;

            } while ((err = GetLastError()) == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

            break;
        }

        rcb = sizeof(MOUNTDEV_NAME) + pmdn->NameLength;

    } while ((err = GetLastError()) == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

    return err;
}

ULONG EnumDiskPartitionsW32(HANDLE hDisk, HANDLE hMountManager)
{
    STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;

    ULONG dwBytesRet;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), &dwBytesRet, NULL))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    if (sdn.DeviceType != FILE_DEVICE_DISK || sdn.PartitionNumber != 0)
    {
        return ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    }

    WCHAR sz[128], *c = sz + swprintf(sz, L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\Harddisk%d\\Partition", sdn.DeviceNumber);

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX pdli;
    };

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb, PartitionCount = 4;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (cb < (rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, PartitionEntry[PartitionCount])))
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, NULL, 0, buf, cb, &dwBytesRet, NULL))
        {
            if (PartitionCount = pdli->PartitionCount)
            {
                PPARTITION_INFORMATION_EX PartitionEntry = pdli->PartitionEntry;

                do 
                {
                    if (!PartitionEntry->PartitionNumber)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    _itow(PartitionEntry->PartitionNumber, c, 10);

                    DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);

                    HANDLE hPartition = CreateFile(sz, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                    if (hPartition != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    {
                        QueryPartitionW32(hPartition, hMountManager);
                        CloseHandle(hPartition);
                    }

                } while (PartitionEntry++, --PartitionCount);
            }

            return NOERROR;
        }

        switch (ULONG err = GetLastError())
        {
        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            PartitionCount = pdli->PartitionCount;
            continue;
        case ERROR_BAD_LENGTH:
        case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
            PartitionCount <<= 1;
            continue;
        default:
            return err;
        }
    }
}

void DiskEnumW32(HANDLE hMountManager)
{
    static const WCHAR DEVCLASS_DISK[] = L"{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}";

    enum { flags = CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLASS|CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT };

    ULONG len;
    if (!CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeW(&len, DEVCLASS_DISK, flags))
    {
        PWSTR buf = (PWSTR)alloca(len * sizeof(WCHAR));

        if (!CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW(DEVCLASS_DISK, buf, len, flags))
        {
            PVOID stack = buf;
            static const WCHAR prefix[] = L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT";

            ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(prefix) + 0x20;

            while (*buf)
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", buf);

                DEVINST dnDevInst;
                if (!CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, buf, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL))
                {
                    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;
                    int err;

                    union {
                        PVOID pv;
                        PWSTR sz;
                        PBYTE pb;
                    };

                    do 
                    {
                        if (cb < rcb)
                        {
                            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                        }

                        rcb -= sizeof(prefix) - sizeof(WCHAR);

                        if (!(err = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, &DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName, &PropertyType, 
                            pb + sizeof(prefix) - sizeof(WCHAR), &rcb, 0)))
                        {
                            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
                            {
                                memcpy(pv, prefix, sizeof(prefix) - sizeof(WCHAR));
                                DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);

                                HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(sz, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                                if (hDisk != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                                {
                                    EnumDiskPartitionsW32(hDisk, hMountManager);
                                    CloseHandle(hDisk);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                err = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
                            }

                            break;
                        }

                        rcb += sizeof(prefix) - sizeof(WCHAR);

                    } while (err == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

                }
                buf += 1 + wcslen(buf);
            }
        }
    }
}

void DiskEnumW32()
{
    HANDLE hMountManager = CreateFile(MOUNTMGR_DOS_DEVICE_NAME, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hMountManager != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DiskEnumW32(hMountManager);
        CloseHandle(hMountManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok wow. Once I get this working, I will accept your answer 10 times if I could... but just, eh, tiny thing - what's that `guz` you give to `alloca(guz)` ?

Comment: @Tar `static volatile UCHAR guz;` this is really 0. i use `alloca(0)` for get top stack pointer, but compiler is very 'smart' and can drop this call. for prevent this i and use `alloca(guz)` - this is have same effect as`alloca(0)` but because i define `guz` as `volatile` this is disable "optimization" and all work as excepted. however this is my (very rare style for allocated memory in stack) you can use yourself way. this is not related direct to question (disk/volumes/etc)

Comment: Still struggling with `DeviceIoControl(hPartition, IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_STABLE_GUID, 0, 0, &guid, sizeof(guid), &dwBytesRet, NULL)`: I get `The request is not supported` (error number 50, or 0x32). I made sure and I have that device mounted (e.g. `\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Harddisk2\Partition0`) with `WinObj`.

Comment: @Tar - this is absolute normal for usb disk. must be. I add this call only for demo (usual only hard disk drive support it)

Comment: @Tar - in function `QueryPartitionW32` first 2 calls for demo only. it result not used. can skip it and begin from `PVOID stack = alloca(guz);` - really need begin with `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution for you, based on PowerShell and WMI alone:

```
$PDO = "\Device\00000052"
$DiskDriverData = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver | Where {$_.PDO -eq $PDO}
$DeviceID = """" + $DiskDriverData.DeviceID.Replace("\","\\") + """"
$ComputerInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem
$name = $ComputerInfo.Name
$FullString = "\\$name\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID=$DeviceID"

$PNPDevice = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPDevice | Where {$_.SystemElement -eq $FullString}

$DiskDriveToPartition = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition | where {$_.Antecedent -eq $PNPDevice.SameElement}

foreach ($i in $DiskDriveToPartition) {
$Partition = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition | Where {$_.Antecedent -eq $i.Dependent}
$PartitionLetter = $Partition.Dependent.split('"')[1]
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Detected Partition for the given PDO: $PartitionLetter"
}
```

Comment: Very useful on another machine, when all I have is powershell - thank you!