# Get information for physical disks when Storage Spaces is enabled

Tags: windows, winapi, hard-drive

I need to get the following information for all of the **physical disks** in the system when Windows 10 storage spaces is enabled.

- Model
- Serial Number
- Firmware Version
- Capacity
- Index of the Disk
- Pnp Id of the disk (to get the SCSI controller name using [CM_Get_Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_parent))
- Location information (Bus number, Target Id and LUN)

What I have tried so far:

1. Used WMI class MSFT_PhysicalDisk
   Although this class gives me the adapter number (so i can do without the disk PNP), the location information it gives is not complete when a disk is connected to a different PCI storage controller (such as the Marvell 92xx SATA 6g controller).
2. Used [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw) with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`, passed the handle to [SetupDiGetDeviceInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinterfaces) and used [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetailw) for location information (Bus/Target Id/LUN), PNP Id, and Device Path. I can pass the device path to [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) and get the rest of the information (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183115) approach). The problem with this is that it does not give me all the physical disks. The disks under the storage spaces pool are omitted.
3. Use an approach similar to the second one but instead of SetupDiGetDeviceInterface and SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail, use [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinfo) and [CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_devnode_registry_propertyw) (using the Disk Drives Guid from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors)). Although this gives me the location and PNP id for all of the physical disks, I can't use anything here (that I know of) to call CreateFile and get the rest of the details.

How can I get the above details for each of the physical disks when storage spaces is enabled?

As a side note, if there is a way to get the disk PNP id from the disk index using the CreateFile and [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa363216(v=VS.85).aspx), that can also be very helpful for me.

Comment: really better use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List`  with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` and other *CM_* api instead *SetupDi* api. `CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW` with `DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` and than `CM_Locate_DevNodeW`. location - `DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo` with `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW` , Capacity, Serial Number - open device and send IOCTLs. really too many questions or you want complete program here

Comment: @RbMm A sample would be much appreciated

Comment: @RbMm Unfortunately using CM_Get_Device_Interface_List also skips over disks in the storage spaces pool

Comment: no, the `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` is perfect working and nothis skip. error in your code

Answer (score 2):

at first we need enumerate all disks in system by call [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) and [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_list_sizew) with [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-disk)

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#undef _NTDDSTOR_H_
#include <ntddstor.h>
#include <ntdddisk.h>

static volatile UCHAR guz;

CONFIGRET EnumDisks(PCSTR prefix, PGUID InterfaceClassGuid)
{
    CONFIGRET err;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    ULONG BufferLen = 0, NeedLen = 256;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PWSTR pszDeviceInterface;
    };

    for(;;) 
    {
        if (BufferLen < NeedLen)
        {
            BufferLen = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca((NeedLen - BufferLen) * sizeof(WCHAR)), stack) / sizeof(WCHAR);
        }

        switch (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(InterfaceClassGuid, 
            0, pszDeviceInterface, BufferLen, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
        {
        case CR_BUFFER_SMALL:
            if (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&NeedLen, InterfaceClassGuid, 
                0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
            {
        default:
            return err;
            }
            continue;

        case CR_SUCCESS:

            while (*pszDeviceInterface)
            {
                DbgPrint("Interface=[%S]\n", pszDeviceInterface);

                HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(pszDeviceInterface, FILE_GENERIC_READ, 
                    FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    GetDiskPropertyByHandle(hFile);
                    CloseHandle(hFile);
                }

                GetPropertyByInterface(prefix, pszDeviceInterface);

                pszDeviceInterface += 1 + wcslen(pszDeviceInterface);
            }

            return CR_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}

CONFIGRET EnumDisks()
{
    char prefix[256];
    memset(prefix, '\t', sizeof(prefix));
    prefix[sizeof(prefix) - 1] = 0;
    prefix[0] = 0;
    return EnumDisks(prefix + sizeof(prefix) - 1, const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK));
}
```

[`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) return multiple, NULL-terminated Unicode strings, each representing the symbolic link name of an interface instance.

from one side this symbolic link name can be passed to `CreateFileW` for open disk device. after this we can set some ioctl to disk - for get

- Index of the Disk
- Capacity
- Serial Number
- Partition Information

example:

```
void GetDiskPropertyByHandle(HANDLE hDisk)
{
    HANDLE hPartition;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
    GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION li;

    NTSTATUS status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hDisk, 0, 0, 0, &iosb,
        IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 0, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn));

    if (0 <= status && sdn.DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_DISK && !sdn.PartitionNumber)
    {
        DbgPrint("\\Device\\Harddisk%d\n", sdn.DeviceNumber);

        WCHAR sz[64], *c = sz + swprintf(sz, L"\\Device\\Harddisk%d\\Partition", sdn.DeviceNumber);

        WCHAR szSize[32];

        if (0 <= (status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hDisk, 0, 0, 0, &iosb,
            IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO, 0, 0, &li, sizeof(li))))
        {
            DbgPrint("Length = %S (%I64x)\n", 
                StrFormatByteSizeW(li.Length.QuadPart, szSize, RTL_NUMBER_OF(szSize)), 
                li.Length.QuadPart);
        }

        UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX pdli;
            PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
            PCSTR psz;
        };

        STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery }; 

        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR) + 0x40, PartitionCount = 4;

        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            switch (status = (NtDeviceIoControlFile(hDisk, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), buf, cb)))
            {
            case STATUS_SUCCESS:
            case STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                if (psdd->Version == sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR))
                {
                    if (psdd->Size > cb)
                    {
                        rcb = psdd->Size;
                        status = STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (psdd->SerialNumberOffset)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("SerialNumber = %s\n", psz + psdd->SerialNumberOffset);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                }
                break;
            }
        } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW);

        for (;;)
        {
            if (cb < (rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, PartitionEntry[PartitionCount])))
            {
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            if (0 <= (status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hDisk, 0, 0, 0, &iosb,
                IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, 0, 0, buf, cb)))
            {
                if (PartitionCount = pdli->PartitionCount)
                {
                    PPARTITION_INFORMATION_EX PartitionEntry = pdli->PartitionEntry;

                    do 
                    {
                        if (!PartitionEntry->PartitionNumber)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        _itow(PartitionEntry->PartitionNumber, c, 10);

                        RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, sz);

                        DbgPrint("%wZ\nOffset=%S ", &ObjectName, 
                            StrFormatByteSizeW(PartitionEntry->StartingOffset.QuadPart, szSize, RTL_NUMBER_OF(szSize)));

                        DbgPrint("Length=%S\n", 
                            StrFormatByteSizeW(PartitionEntry->PartitionLength.QuadPart, szSize, RTL_NUMBER_OF(szSize)));

                        char PartitionName[256], *szPartitionName;

                        switch (PartitionEntry->PartitionStyle)
                        {
                        case PARTITION_STYLE_MBR:
                            DbgPrint("MBR: type=%x boot=%x", PartitionEntry->Mbr.PartitionType, PartitionEntry->Mbr.BootIndicator);
                            break;
                        case PARTITION_STYLE_GPT:

                            if (IsEqualGUID(PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_ENTRY_UNUSED_GUID))
                            {
                                szPartitionName = "UNUSED";
                            }
                            else if (IsEqualGUID(PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_SYSTEM_GUID))
                            {
                                szPartitionName = "SYSTEM";
                            }
                            else if (IsEqualGUID(PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_MSFT_RESERVED_GUID))
                            {
                                szPartitionName = "RESERVED";
                            }
                            else if (IsEqualGUID(PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID))
                            {
                                szPartitionName = "DATA";
                            }
                            else if (IsEqualGUID(PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_MSFT_RECOVERY_GUID))
                            {
                                szPartitionName = "RECOVERY";
                            }
                            else if (IsEqualGUID(PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_MSFT_SNAPSHOT_GUID))
                            {
                                szPartitionName = "SNAPSHOT";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sprintf(szPartitionName = PartitionName, "{%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x}", 
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data1,
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data2,
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data3,
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[0],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[1],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[2],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[3],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[4],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[5],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[6],
                                    PartitionEntry->Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[7]);
                            }
                            DbgPrint("[%s] %I64x \"%S\"", 
                                szPartitionName,
                                PartitionEntry->Gpt.Attributes,
                                PartitionEntry->Gpt.Name);
                            break;
                        }

                        if (0 <= NtOpenFile(&hPartition, FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb,
                            FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT))
                        {
                            union {
                                BYTE bb[sizeof(FILE_FS_ATTRIBUTE_INFORMATION) + 32*sizeof(WCHAR) ];
                                FILE_FS_ATTRIBUTE_INFORMATION ffai;
                            };

                            switch (NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(hPartition, &iosb, &ffai, sizeof(bb), FileFsAttributeInformation))
                            {
                            case STATUS_SUCCESS:
                            case STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                                DbgPrint(" \"%.*S\"\n", ffai.FileSystemNameLength >> 1 , ffai.FileSystemName);
                                break;
                            }

                            NtClose(hPartition);
                        }

                    } while (PartitionEntry++, --PartitionCount);
                }
                return ;
            }

            switch (status)
            {
            case STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                PartitionCount = pdli->PartitionCount;
                continue;
            case STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
            case STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL:
                PartitionCount <<= 1;
                continue;
            default:
                return ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

from another size we can get [*Device Instance ID*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids) from interface string by call [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_propertyw) with [`DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-instanceid). after this we call [`CM_Locate_DevNodeW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_locate_devnodew) for get device instance handle.

```
CONFIGRET GetPropertyByInterface(PCSTR prefix, PCWSTR pszDeviceInterface)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 256;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    CONFIGRET status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR DeviceID;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW(pszDeviceInterface, &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                DbgPrint("%sDeviceID = %S\n", prefix, DeviceID);

                DEVINST dnDevInst; 

                if (CR_SUCCESS == (status = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, DeviceID, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL)))
                {
                    GetPropertyByDeviceID(prefix, dnDevInst);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    return status;
}
```

with device instance handle we can query many device properties via [`CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_devnode_propertyw) like:
[`DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-locationinfo), [`DEVPKEY_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-name--device-interface-), [`DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-pdoname), `DEVPKEY_Device_FirmwareVersion`, `DEVPKEY_Device_Model`, [`DEVPKEY_Device_DriverVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-driverversion) and many others - look full list in *devpkey.h*

finally we can call [`CM_Get_Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_parent) and recursive query all this properties for parent device(s) until we not rich top of stack:

```
#define OPEN_PDO

void GetPropertyByDeviceID(PCSTR prefix, DEVINST dnDevInst)
{
#ifdef OPEN_PDO
    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
#endif

    CONFIGRET status;

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x80;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR sz;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    static struct  
    {
        CONST DEVPROPKEY *PropertyKey;
        PCWSTR PropertyName;
    } PropertyKeys[] = {
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName, L"PDOName"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_Parent, L"Parent"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_DriverVersion, L"DriverVersion"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo, L"LocationInfo"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_FirmwareVersion, L"FirmwareVersion"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_Model, L"Model"},
        { &DEVPKEY_NAME, L"NAME"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, L"DeviceID"}
    };

    do 
    {
        int n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(PropertyKeys);

        do 
        {
            CONST DEVPROPKEY *PropertyKey = PropertyKeys[--n].PropertyKey;

            do 
            {
                if (cb < rcb)
                {
                    rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                }

                status = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, PropertyKey, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

                if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%s%S=[%S]\n", prefix, PropertyKeys[n].PropertyName, sz);

#ifdef OPEN_PDO

                        if (!n)
                        {
                            // DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName can use in NtOpenFile

                            RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, sz);

                            if (0 <= NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|SYNCHRONIZE, &oa,
                                &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT))
                            {
                                NtClose(hFile);
                            }
                        }
#endif
                    }
                }

            } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

        } while (n);

        if (!*--prefix) break;

    } while (CM_Get_Parent(&dnDevInst, dnDevInst, 0) == CR_SUCCESS);
}
```

also string returned by [`DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-pdoname) we can use in [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntopenfile) call for open PDO device.

Comment: This had the same issue I was having before. CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW skips over disks that are part of Microsoft Storage Spaces. +1 because it is full of helpful pointers. Ultimately if figured it out with the help of another question you answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439253/2631220
I used the approach 3 in my question and called CreateFile with the physical device object (which I did not know was possible).

Comment: @AliZahid - i not familiar with Storage Spaces, but `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` is nothing skip. it return exactly list of devices which implement interface (by guid). if you not got some devices - this mean that this device **not implement** requested interface. so think disks from SS (RAID, implemented in software) simply not implement `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`. you need use some another interface for list this

Comment: @AliZahid - for example exist `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` interface but some volume listed only under `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HIDDEN_VOLUME`.. also look [Get physical disk mapping for Win 8 Storage Spaces virtual disks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/de5f3123-3f8f-43cd-b85c-c754986a6250/get-physical-disk-mapping-for-win-8-storage-spaces-virtual-disks?forum=wdk).. need look in winobj and devicetree for it devices and which interfaces it implement